# possible ways to include a tag file (jstl custom tag) into jsp

Tags: jsp, tags, include, jstl

Are there other possible ways to include a tag file (jstl custom tag) into a jsp file than the one via .tld file?

is it possible to use the include mechanism? `<jsp:include page="bla.tagx"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any .tld file to use tags implemented as tag files. The tags must simply be put under `WEB-INF/tags`, and be declared in the JSP using

```
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="myTags" %>
```

More information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnama.html).

Comment: you`re right, but that doesnt solve my problem.. I have a variable containing the tag file name.. so I want to dynamically load the tag that is inside the variable. is that possible?

Comment: No, it's not possible AFAIK.

Comment: there isnt a mechanism for that?

Comment: None that I'm aware of. BTW, how would you pass arguments to the tag?

Comment: hmm.. good question.. never thought about that.. Looks like it really is not possible..